# (JSF 2.0) Problems with primefaces dataTable component. 

Tags: java, jsf, browser, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

I want to make a simple datatable just with the pagination feature, but i have 2 problems:

1- The data is displayed but the paginator is not shown in the browser(I tried IE and chrome)

```
<p:dataTable var="garbage" value="#{resultsController.allGarbage}" paginator="true" rows="10">          

        <p:column>  
        <f:facet name="header">  
        <h:outputText value="Filename" />  
        </f:facet>  
        <h:outputText value="#{garbage.filename}" />
         </p:column> 

        <p:column>  
        <f:facet name="header">  
        <h:outputText value="Description" />  
        </f:facet>  
        <h:outputText value="#{garbage.description}" />  
         </p:column> 

        <p:column>  
        <f:facet name="header">  
        <h:outputText value="Upload date" />  
        </f:facet>  
        <h:outputText value="#{garbage.uploadDate}" /> 
         </p:column>                
</p:dataTable>
```

2- In google chrome paginator still is not displayed and also i see some extrange dialog every time i refresh:

[image]

Does this mean that primefaces is not compatible with chrome?

------------------------UPDATE 1------------------------------

This is how it looks the hold page:

```
<ui:composition template="WEB-INF/templates/BasicTemplate.xhtml">
<ui:define name="resultsForm">
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h:inputText id="search" value="" /><h:commandButton value="search"/>
    <h:selectOneRadio id="searchFilter" value="" >
            <f:selectItem id="r1" itemLabel="text documents(.pdf, .docx ...)" />
            <f:selectItem id="r2" itemLabel="audio(.mp3,.wav...)" />
            <f:selectItem id="r3" itemLabel="multimedia(.mpeg,flv...)" />
            <f:selectItem id="r4" itemLabel="other..." />               
    </h:selectOneRadio> 

    <p:dataTable var="garbage" value="#{resultsController.allGarbage}" paginator="true" rows="10"  
             paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  
             rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">         

            <p:column>  
            <f:facet name="header">  
            <h:outputText value="Filename" />  
            </f:facet>  
            <h:outputText value="#{garbage.filename}" />
             </p:column> 

            <p:column>  
            <f:facet name="header">  
            <h:outputText value="Description" />  
            </f:facet>  
            <h:outputText value="#{garbage.description}" />  
             </p:column> 

            <p:column>  
            <f:facet name="header">  
            <h:outputText value="Upload date" />  
            </f:facet>  
            <h:outputText value="#{garbage.uploadDate}" /> 
             </p:column>                
    </p:dataTable> 
</h:form>
</ui:define>
```

------------------------UPDATE 2------------------------------

This image is how the component is displayed in chrome and how the chrome consoles displays an error:
[image]

Comment: Have u tried with Opera or FF?

Comment: Yeah it doesnt work in any. I just cant understant why the paginationis not being displayed? I do exactly as it says in http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatablePagination.jsf

Comment: Is your table nested inside any other primefaces or jsf component? If yes you could try it outside of these sourrounding components.

Comment: Is the dataTable inside a form. Try to put that inside a `h:form`

Comment: Yes it is inside a form now i will update how it looks like the hold component.

Comment: Does Chrome's JS-console report any error?

Comment: Yes it says: Uncaught ReferenceError: PrimeFaces is not defined. What i am supossed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't see any PrimeFaces specific CSS/JS imports in generated HTML `<head>` (rightclick page in browser, choose *View Source*, then it means that you need to replace the HTML `<head>` in your template by JSF `<h:head>`. That's namely where all resource dependencies (CSS/JS/images/etc which are connected to JSF components/libraries) will end up in.

In former PrimeFaces versions (at least in 2.0) you would also need to configure a resource servlet to that PrimeFaces can serve them up from the JAR file:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.primefaces.resource.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/primefaces_resource/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I'm however not sure about the newer PrimeFaces versions beyond 2.0, also currently the user manual is for some reason not free anymore.

Comment: That worked now thank you. But i still dont understand why everytime i want to use prime faces i have to add those script tags. Can i avoid doing that somehow? Thanks again.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid that? It's just part of PrimeFaces core functionality and look'n'feel, so that you don't need to write it yourself.

Comment: Ok i think i understand now. I just thought that i could use all the prime-faces components without the need of mentioning what script files they need.

Comment: You don't need to mention them at all. They should automatically end up in head if you use `<h:head>`. Did you understand my answer?

Comment: No. I didn't said that anywhere. It look like that you're mixing my answer with the one of Matt Handy. All I said was to just replace `<head>` by `<h:head>` and if necessary also configure the `ResourceServlet`. That's all.

Comment: Yes i did understand now sorry. Sometimes i have to read things a couple of times. I am not english native :)

Comment: Hi BalusC. In PF2.0, you dont have to create `Resource Servlet` in your web.xml anymore. I bought a commercial guide for 2.2. I can send it to you if you like :D

Answer (score 1):

From the JS error it seems that the PrimeFaces javascript libraries are not correctly included.

I had the same issue with mojarra ("mojarra is not defined" in js console). It seems that for some reason the js libs are not included (should be done by the server). Sometimes they are, sometimes not (never found out the reason).

**If anyone reading this has an idea, I would be thankful for any hint.**

For mojarre my workaround was to include mojarra's js lib manually.

Regarding to your problem, try the same for Primefaces.

In my project there is a page that uses p:dataTable and pagination. The following js files are included (plus some others; shown in source of html output):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/register/primefaces_resource/2.1/yui/datasource/datasource-min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/register/primefaces_resource/2.1/primefaces/paginator/paginator.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/register/primefaces_resource/2.1/yui/datatable/datatable-min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/register/primefaces_resource/2.1/primefaces/datatable/datatable.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/register/primefaces_resource/2.1/yui/swf/swf-min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/register/primefaces_resource/2.1/yui/charts/charts-min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/register/primefaces_resource/2.1/primefaces/charts/charts.js"></script>
```

Look in your html ouput and check if the pagination-related js files are included. If not, include them manually. Note that `/register` in the src attributes is my context path. Replace it with your context path.

Comment: I just saw the view source in the output, those scripts are not there. should i download them from somewhere and add them to my WEB-INF/lib folder? How should i include them manually? i never did that in eclipse.

Comment: No, they are there in the primefaces.jar (is it in your classpath, e.g. project's lib folder?). If you (successfully) use primefaces components on other pages you could copy the include dir there.

Comment: Yes the primefaces-2.2.1.jar is in my lib folder, but i dont understand what should i add into my results.xhtml page. Should i add those script tags in to the head tag of my page?

Comment: Example: If your context path is /project, try to add the following to the header of your results.xhtml: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/project/primefaces_resource/2.2.1/primefaces/paginator/paginator.js"></script>`

Comment: I added this: <script type="text/javascript" src="/GarbageTheWeb/primefaces_resource/2.1/primefaces/charts/charts.js"></script> But it does not work. How can i know if that path is correct? How to i check my path?

Comment: Do you have other pages of your project where primefaces components work correctly? If yes copy the correct path from one of these. btw you use primefaces 2.2.1. Your path should contain 2.2.1 and not 2.1

Comment: I dont have other pages that use primefaces, so i dont know how that path looks like. I use 2.2.1 that was a fat finger. How can i know my context path? Notice that i am ussing this dataTable in the composite page, i dont have head tag there so i added the scripts in to the template head tag. Could that be the reason why is not working?

Comment: Here the solution to the dialog problem in chrome http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/15182/how-to-disable-individual-plug-ins-in-google-chrome/ There is a conflict with some skype plugin. Now i dont see the error. The problem with the pager not fixed yet.