# Why this errors appear in my console?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

I just noticed some rare error messages on my browser console, but i don't know what is the reason. I use some primefaces gadgets in my app, it all works fine, but when i navigate from one page to another i keep see this in the console:
[image]

I don't know what is wrong. I just want to mention that all my pages use one same template, that has the navigation gadget you see in the image above. In that template at the head tag i added this scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
            src="/primefaces_resource/2.1/yui/utilities/utilities.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"
            src="/primefaces_resource/2.1/yui/datasource/datasource-min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"
            src="/primefaces_resource/2.1/primefaces/paginator/paginator.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"
            src="/primefaces_resource/2.1/yui/datatable/datatable-min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"
            src="/primefaces_resource/2.1/primefaces/datatable/datatable.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"
            src="/primefaces_resource/2.1/yui/swf/swf-min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"
            src="/primefaces_resource/2.1/yui/charts/charts-min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"
            src="/primefaces_resource/2.1/primefaces/charts/charts.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"
            src="/primefaces_resource/2.1/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"
            src="/primefaces_resource/2.1/primefaces/core/core.js"></script>    
        <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"
        type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

This is the jars i added to my classpath to be able to use primefaces:
[image]

I dont understand why do i see those messages all the time in the console?

Comment: search for these `js` in your extracted war ..

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean. I did not extract any war. I justhave the primefaces-2.2.1.jar in my project libraries

Comment: your server does.. anyways.. check in the war if it is there?

Comment: Ok but how can i find that war? Where is it?

Comment: there are many utility to do this. or even you can look for them at proper place..

Comment: I just posted an image with the jar file i added to my project.Sorry but i still don't understand what you want me to do. What tool should i use to check if the war file contains those .js files?

Comment: I hope [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457421/jsf-2-0-problems-with-primefaces-datatable-component) isn't the issue

Comment: No i think not. I do have the `<h:head>` in my template and also the resource servlet in my web.xml. What it could be? I just see that error, but the application works correctly i can login,logout, register... and the primefaces components i added seem to work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the `h:head` tag in your page then you should not need to include these separate `script` tags. Primefaces should figure out which components are used in the page and output the needed scripts itself.

The 404 error are probably caused by a wrong absolute path. Unless your application is explicitly deployd at the webserver root, you need to prepend the context root path of your. You can access the context path using el like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="#{request.contextPath}/primefaces_resource/2.1/yui/utilities/utilities.js"></script>
```

Comment: I did remove all the scripts from the h:head tag and the app seems to works fine. So i didn't need them. What about later when i decide to deploy in the real server. Will i need to add something to my head tag?
Thank you!

Comment: If you use `<h:head>` instead of `<head>` then you do not need to add them manually.

Comment: @sfrj: Please check the generated html from your browser, the script tags should be added by primefaces if you used any components on that page. The code snippet above using `request.contextPath` might be useful if you need to include additional scripts that are not part of primefaces.

Comment: I just check, i looked at the page source and i see the scripts in those pages where there are primefaces components. Now is fine. Thanks again.